# Referrer policy problem? PDF Attachment shows blank on Chrome only (multiple Computers)

Tags: wordpress, pdf, policy, referrer, referrer-policy

I have links to PDFs on my site that open the attached PDF file in a new tab. Usually, the new tab opens and the PDF shows just fine. You can scroll it and browse it.

Up until today, there's been no problem. Now all of a sudden, when I click the attachment, the new tab opens but the page remains grey. This only happens with Chrome. I can use another browser and it will show. This is consistent on any computer I try this on.

In developer tools on console it gives the error message as follows:
Failed to set referrer policy: The value '' is not one of 'no-referrer', 'no-referrer-when-downgrade', 'origin', 'origin-when-cross-origin', 'same-origin', 'strict-origin', 'strict-origin-when-cross-origin', or 'unsafe-url'. The referrer policy has been left unchanged.

Any ideas how to resolve this and get the PDFs to open and display on Chrome?
Also for reference this is a WordPress site 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your site has a ServiceWorker, there's a bug in Chrome 71 that is causing an issue. Details here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=918944

My fix was to essentially tell my SW to simply return the pdf request if detected. I'm sure there are more elegant ways, but I put the following line near the top of my `fetch` event.

```
if( request.url.indexOf('.pdf') !== -1 ){ return; }
```

If you're not using a SW, try adding `rel="noopener noreferrer"` to the link.

Comment: Incredible! Worked perfectly. The error was coming from the plug-in, Super Progressive Web Apps. I added the code you mentioned, if( request.url.indexOf('.pdf') !== -1 ){ return; } to the php file. Adding rel="noopener noreferrer" didn't work.